# I need help identifying a bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Basically this tiny bug plopped on top of my laptop keyboard. And as much as I disdained bugs, this one didn't look like anything I've ever seen. It had something that resembled bits of a dandelion on its back, and its body seemed like half a moth/ whatever insect. After closer inspection, I thought it was just a dying moth, the thing on its back being clipped wings and its body cut in half... but when i tried to shove it off the keyboard with my pen, it jumped about a hundred times its width onto my wall - instantly. Tried to get a second picture but it jumped again/disappeared... no idea where it went, or what it was... Here's the picture I took, and a quick sketch of what it looked like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an immature passionvine hopper (*Scolypopa australis*).  They are informally known as fluffy bums.

[image]

Source: http://ketenewplymouth.peoplesnetworknz.info/friends_of_te_henui/images/show/1486-nymphs-fluffy-bums-scolypopa-australis

This is am image of the adult stage from the [Encyclopedia of Life](http://eol.org/pages/237023/details) site:

[image]

More information can be found at the Encyclopedia of Life link above.  It appears that their distribution may be only in Australia and New Zealand and I'm not sure where this photo was taken so take this information into consideration.